# How to use metric with three inputs(GAP metric) in Keras while training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

This is GAP metric code from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/davidthaler/gap-metric)

```py
def GAP(pred, conf, true):
    x = pd.DataFrame({'pred': pred, 'conf': conf, 'true': true})
    x.sort_values('conf', ascending=False, inplace=True, na_position='last')
    x['correct'] = (x.true == x.pred).astype(int)
    x['prec_k'] = x.correct.cumsum() / (np.arange(len(x)) + 1)
    x['term'] = x.prec_k * x.correct
    gap = x.term.sum() / x.true.count()

    return gap
```

I want to use it while training, but it get `conf` argument - vector of probability or confidence scores for prediction. But metrics must get only two arguments. Does any possibility to use it like this:

```py
model.compile(loss='my_loss',metrics=[GAP])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. There is a way you can do this with a small tweak. Note that frameworks like Keras support loss functions and metrics of the form `fun(true, pred)`. The function definition should be in this form only.

Also, the second limitation is, the shapes of both `true` and `pred` must be same.

Tweaking the first limitation: Concatenate the two output tensors into one. Suppose you have `x` number of output classes, then shape of `conf` and `pred` will be `(None, x)`. You can concatenate these two tensors into one producing `final_output` with shape `(None, 2, x)`.

Doing this is only the first step. It won't work unless we tweak the second limitation.

Now let us tweak the second limitation: This limitation can be shortened to: "The dimensions of both these tensors must be same." Note that I am trying to reduce the limitation from shape to dimensions. This can be done by having dynamic shapes, for ex: `shape(true) = (None, 1, x) and shape(pred) = (None, None, x)` will not throw errors as `None` can take any value at runtime. In short, add a layer at the end of the model to combine outputs and that layer should have dynamic output shape.

But in your case, `true` will also have shape `(None, x)`. You can just expand dimensions of this tensor at `axis=1` to get `(None, 1, x)` and then the newly generated true can be provided as input to the model.

Note that as you are combining **two** tensors, the `final_output` will always have shape `(None, 2, x)` which isn't equal to `(None, 1, x)`. But as we have configured the last layer to return dynamic shape i.e. `(None, None, x)`, this will not be a problem at compile time. And Keras never checks for shape mismatch at runtime **except an operation on tensor causes that error**.

Now, that you have `final_output` with same shape as `true`, you just need to slice the `final_output` to get back the original two tensors `pred` and `conf` in your custom loss function and metrics.

The above was purely logical.. To see an example implementation, check out layers and loss function [here](https://github.com/ParikhKadam/bidaf-keras).